# Unity GameObject Width and Height set to zero but still displaying as normal

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a GameObject in a scene but not in the Canvas. In this GameObject I am instantiating a couple of other GameObjects without any problems.

What I do not understand is that, it doesn't matter if I set the main GameObject's Width and Height to 0 or 100 or 1000, nothing changes, it will still instantiate and display everything in the same way.

Can someone please explain me why it still displaying everything when I set the main GameObject's  width and height to 0?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## `RectTransforms` only matter to Canvas objects

Width and Height are properties only available to `RectTransform` type Transforms and only matter for Canvas objects. For non-canvas objects you should just use a normal `Transform` at which point you will have a scale parameter, which setting it to zero, will make the object have zero size.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information. I change it from `RectTransform` to `Transform`.